# Unable to use Network: "Not Registered On Network"

Tags: sms, calls, connection-issues, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-chat

I am using Samsung Galaxy Chat B5330 (officially upgraded from 4.0.4 to 4.1.2). It used to work fine, but since a few days I am not able to call or send sms or use any network related services. It gives me error : "Not Registered On Network". I tried applying manual network settings. At first it gives a pop up : "Registered on Network". But as soon as I try to make a call, the same error : "Not Registered On Network".

I thought that factory reset would have been the solution to my problem, but unexpectedly , this too did not work for me. Please help.

Comment: I don't know your device, so forgive my stupid question: Does it work with a SIM card? If so, have you tried that SIM in a different phone – and a different SIM in yours? Maybe the SIM has trouble.

Comment: tried with the same sim card in different phone, it works fine there, and also tried inserting different sim card in my phone, still "Not Registered on Network".

Comment: Sounds like a case for support then (trouble with the SIM slot). Sometimes it's just the contacts: you could try making the SIM "thicker" by sticking something to its back, so it gets pressed harder to the contacts. If that also doesn't work: Service time.

Comment: some simcards work on my phone, i realise today that a roaming network sim card does not work on my phone, whereas that with home network works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your SIM (Subscriber Identification Module) and if necessary get a new one from your service provider - If it is corrupted then you would not be allowed to sign on to the network. A factory Reset only wipes the device itself, not the SIM.

Comment: my sim card works fine on all other phones except mine, and other sim cards also don't work on my phone.

Comment: perhaps you have a flaky card slot - if the SIM is working in other phones and just not yours - I would check the card slot so you may need to service the device or try a new SIM card from the service provider..

Comment: some simcards work on my phone, i realise today that a roaming network sim card does not work on my phone, whereas that with home network works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you try to call anyone the error message says “NOT REGISTERED ON NETWORK“. I was fascinated this error in my samsung phone, so I was working on this issue and trying to solve this issue.

[How To Fix NOT REGISTERED ON NETWORK In Samsung or Android Phones](http://www.wiknix.com/how-to-fix-not-registered-on-network-in-samsung-or-android-phones/)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.